# How can i use an SQL query to pull the following infromation from a singlet bale.

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a giant table that gets updated constantly and i need to pull some information from it but i am having trouble wrapping my head around how.

Basically i have a single table with three fields... 
Username - app_name - start_time

Each time a user opens an app here in my environment, a row is created in the table. I need to generate a report that contains every app ever logged into by each user and the most recent start time for that app for that user. I'm really struggling with understanding what I need to do. I think i need to do some sort of join but its on the same table and even then, i don't think a join is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be this simple.

```
select username
, app_name
, max(start_time) mostRecent
from yourtable
group by username, app_name
```